# How to handle "obsolete" packages when upgrading distribution?

Tags: debian, dist-upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Debian machine from Jessie to Stretch, but aptitude is reporting that I have 19 obsolete packages. Some of these, like BerkeleyDB, I use routinely.

A [set of upgrade instructions](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch) say to remove any obsolete software before doing the upgrade, but I want to continue using some of the software. Am I stuck using Jessie forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the packages don't conflict with new/updated packages in stretch, there's no particular reason why you should remove them.

If they do conflict, the package manager will let you know.

BTW, I still have some packages installed on my system that haven't been in debian for a decade or two.  They still work.  I've had others that I had to recompile for newer debian releases, and a few more that I stopped using because they weren't worth the bother of re-compiling (or, more commonly, hacking so that they compiled against the newer versions of various libraries).

I still have old versions of libdb installed:

```
$ dpkg -l libdb[0-9.]* | grep ii
ii  libdb4.6           4.6.21-21      amd64        Berkeley v4.6 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb4.6++         4.6.21-18      amd64        Berkeley v4.6 Database Libraries for C++ [runtime]
ii  libdb5.1:amd64     5.1.29-7       amd64        Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.1:i386      5.1.29-7       i386         Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.3:amd64     5.3.28-13.1+b1 amd64        Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.3:i386      5.3.28-13.1+b1 i386         Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.3-dev       5.3.28-13.1+b1 amd64        Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [development]
ii  libdb5.3-sql:amd64 5.3.28-13.1+b1 amd64        Berkeley v5.3 Database Libraries [SQL runtime]
```

libdb4.6 hasn't been in Debian since "Squeeze" (Debian 6), around 2014.

I purge them occasionally when I have nothing installed that uses the old libs...if/when I remember.

Comment: Ok, so should I infer from your answer that leaving the package there and upgrading can only break the package. It can't break the upgrade?

Comment: No, it won't break the upgrade (and usually won't even break the package).  You'll just have some obsolete packages installed on your upgraded system...no big deal.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to remove the obsolete package , an obsolete package is no available on the newest repository and may cause a security problems.

To list the obsolete package:

```
aptitude search ?obsolete
```

Make a list :

```
aptitude search ?obsolete  > mylist
```

Edit your `mylist` file by keeping only the package names.

To remove the obsolete package:

```
apt-get --purge remove $(cat mylist)
```

Debian handbook : [4.8. Obsolete packages](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#obsolete)

> Introducing lots of new packages, stretch also retires and omits quite a few old packages that were in jessie. It provides no upgrade path for these obsolete packages. While nothing prevents you from continuing to use an obsolete package where desired, the Debian project will usually discontinue security support for it a year after stretch's release[5], and will not normally provide other support in the meantime. Replacing them with available alternatives, if any, is recommended.

Comment: obsolete packages aren't a general security problem (although some specific packages may be - same as non-obsolete packages), and just blindly removing all "obsolete" packages will probably remove things you are using (including, e.g., roxterm on my system).  BTW, with `aptitude search ?obsolete`, the package name is sometimes in the third field, because there are flags in the second.  try `awk '$4 == "-" {print $3; next}; {print $2}'` (the field immediately after the package name is always a "-")

Comment: i also recommend `aptitude search ?obsolete > obsolete`, editing that file with `vi` or whatever to remove any packages you want to keep from that file, and then extracting the pkg names to purge with awk or whatever.

Comment: @cas the output of `aptitude` look like `i    Package Description `  , the first field is for the stat of package (i , p , d , ...) , the second field for the package name , the third field for description.

Comment: The output is **usually** like that.  Not always.  When I ran it, I saw numerous packages listed with an `A` in the second field.  On those output lines, the third field was the package name.   e.g. `i A cpp-4.9 - GNU C preprocessor`.   the field after the package name is always a `-`, so using that to decide whether to output $2 or $3 works.

Comment: from the man page, it looks like it uses the first 3 characters, fixed width.  If the third character is an `A`, it means it was auto-installed.  The first two characters seem to be reserved for dpkg-like install/status flags.

Comment: @cas Agreed , thank you for this explanation , i have update my answer. Right when the `A` character  is displayed on the `aptitude` output the package_name will be on the 3rd field.

Answer (score 0):

...you'd never be "stuck using it forever" :)
Just a question of how & when you get past this problem...

So there are 3 upgrade flags for apt:

https://www.fosslinux.com/43884/apt-vs-aptitude.htm
https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude

```
apt upgrade | safe-upgrade
```

this will upgrade everything in your Ubuntu install

...except whatever conflicts with the full-upgrade package list

```
apt full-upgrade
```

...and remove anything that conflicts with the full-upgrade package list

note that the TUI version of aptitude (just run `aptitude` on the command-line) has many more options and may or may not help guide your decisions better than the command-line version. Another good use for the LiveCD. The TUI version is also good for grouping applications, drivers etc. into easy-to-manage categories. So if you do the upgrade and there are still obsolete packages on your system, you'll be able to find them easily in the TUI version of aptitude.

RH package-management is conceptually similar but uses a different set of procedures to accomplish similar goals...likewise your other option is to just find an updated software package or a different method to achieve the same results. That way you won't be stuck running U14-32bit in 2025. Which you could do on a VM or in a container.

Anyway I'd back-up the install, run the safe-upgrade and see if it still works. If not, restore it to a VM or find an updated substitute. Or as you said, just buy a new box and remote into your old one.

Personally I do upgrades to overwrite and disable old/incompatible software, to break a legacy platform & inspire a move forward...if I need something to work on it (a driver or a sw package) then I won't upgrade. It's better to just buy another box and move forward. If you really REALLY need it to work then you wouldn't want to take a chance on upgrading the OS on the one box that you have working, would you? You'd at least clone the old install onto a new drive and upgrade the new drive, right? If it doesn't work after a full upgrade with perhaps a reinstall of the required sw (which hopefully will work ok with newer libraries), then just clone the old drive back onto the new one then try a safe upgrade. Dual-boot, whatever it takes.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side, one could search for the obsolete packages that were automatically installed, have no other packages depending on them, and are not essential:

```
aptitude search '~o ~M !?reverse-depends(~i) !~E'
```

Where the [patterns](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#tableSearchTermQuickGuide) mean:

- obsolete: `~o` or `?obsolete`
- automatically installed: `~M` or `?automatic`
- no other packages depend on it: `!?reverse-depends(~i)`
- not essential: `!~E` or `!?essential`

Therefore, a one-liner to safely remove (purge) obsolete packages could be:

```
aptitude purge $(aptitude search '~o ~M !?reverse-depends(~i) !~E' | cut -d' ' -f 3 | paste -sd' ')
```